# Superset Cannot access to ClickHouse DB

Tags: clickhouse, apache-superset

Superset cannot access to ClickHouse and produces this below error message:

```json
ERROR: {"error": "Connection failed!
The error message returned was:
Code: 516, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: default: Authentication failed: password is incorrect or there is no user with such name (version 20.3.4.10 (official build))"}
```

URI String is :

```sh
clickhouse://default:1234@195.87.222.11:8123/tutorial
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is the bug in [sqlalchemy-clickhouse](https://github.com/cloudflare/sqlalchemy-clickhouse), to fix need to manually downgrade the package *infi.clickhouse_orm* up to version 1.0.4:

```sh
pip install infi.clickhouse_orm==1.0.4
```

See more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61722790/303298).